# php number figures

Tags: php

Here are some numbers, from 1 - 50, **how to output the number `5,15,25,35,45`** ?

I use some code like this, but is also will output `10,20,30,40,50`. Thanks.

```
<?php
  for ($n = 1; $n <= 50; $n++) {
    if ($n%5 == 0 ){
      echo "<p>".$n."<p><br />"; // do stuff
    }   
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for ($n = 5; $n <= 45; $n += 10) {
    echo $n;
}
```

or

```
echo join(', ', range(5, 45, 10));
```

or

```
foreach (range(5, 45, 10) as $n) {
    echo $n;
}
```

or any other combination thereof.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition should fix this

```
if ($n % 5 == 0 && $n % 10 != 0)
```

But the alternative strategy offered by @deceze is better.

Answer (score 0):

Test for `$n%10 != 0`too.

```
<?php
  for ($n = 1; $n <= 50; $n++) {
    if (($n%5 == 0) && ($n%10 != 0)){
      echo "<p>".$n."<p><br />"; // do stuff
    }   
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second comparison:

```
if ($n%5 == 0 && $n%10 != 0)
```

This will be true only if it's a multiple of 5 but not multiple of 10.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
  for ($n = 1; $n <= 50; $n++) {
    if (($n%5 == 0) && ($n%2==1) ){
      echo "<p>".$n."<p><br />"; // do stuff
    }   
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($n = 1; $n <= 50; $n++) {
    if ($n%10==5){
      echo "<p>".$n."<p><br />"; // do stuff
    }   
  }
```